# Can we replace the Cu electrode with Ag in a Daniell Cell?

Tags: electrochemistry

In a Daniell cell, the reaction at the anode involves the oxidation of zinc metal atoms to zinc(2+) ions, and the reaction at the cathode involves the reduction of copper(2+) ions to copper metal atoms. The copper metal atoms get deposited onto the copper electrode. As far as I can see, the copper electrode itself is not involved in the reaction, except as a conductor and a place for the newly formed copper atoms to deposit. Is the electrode involved in any other way? If not, I should be able to replace the copper electrode with a silver electrode as long as it is still in CuSO4 solution. Can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The silver electrode would become a copper electrode, with copper depositing on it in the galvanic cell mode.

The copper electrode is involved.

The open circuit state:

$$\ce{Cu(s) <=> Cu^2+(aq) + 2 e-}$$

The galvanic/voltaic state;

$$\ce{Cu(s) <<=> Cu^2+(aq) + 2 e-}$$

The electrolytic)charging state;

$$\ce{Cu(s) <=>> Cu^2+(aq) + 2 e-}$$

It is analogical to thermal energy exchange between cold and warm objects at molecular level. It happens always in both directions, with the net value positive, zero, or negative.